# Apple Developer and AppStore Cert Not genrated in codename one

Tags: codenameone

Our app working fine for past 2 months on generation of .ipa and device specific builds. Last 2 days we are getting Developer Cert Not generated and Apple Cert Not generated. Could please help on this

I have created provisional certificates and downloads with specific devices I am getting files with .mobileprovision which are not accepted in IOS tabs.

[image]

Please look into and send me some resolutions for this

Please find Error log information at end of the file
https://s3.amazonaws.com/codenameone-build-response/64deba95-aa3f-4471-a805-35e57ef46cdb-1471866430515-error.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI I suggest moving to the new certificate wizard that's within the `Codename One Settings` tool.

There seems to be an issue which may be temporary so it might work if you retry. If this is still happening let us know and we will seek a permanent fix for it.

As a workaround if the issue is still there you can login to your Apple developer account and revoke your certificates then re-run the certificate wizard. It should work as the process failure is during the revoke stage.

Notice that revoking certificates should have no affect on apps in production.

Comment: This should be fixed now. Apple changed some things in the certificate generation process and we deployed a server fix on our side. This should start "just working" with no update on your side as we use a webservice to mask such "hiccups".

Comment: This isn't working for me at the moment. As above, I'm getting the Cert not generated. I've tried revoking the certificates in my apple developer account.

Comment: There was an issue we just fixed last night so please try again

Comment: Great thanks. Works on the old certificate signing tool (the one from project settings), but no the new one. It generates the certificates but doesn't install them.

Comment: Odd, we'll look into that.